# How to access data name from a list of time-series in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, time-series

I'm newbie in programming and came across with a problem that I don't know how to solve.

Trying to run some tests in time series, such as adf.test() and kpss.test(). The example above is using adf.test():

```
library(tseries)

air = ts(AirPassengers)
co2 = ts(co2)
lista = list(air,co2)
table1 = data.frame()

for (i in lista){ table1 = rbind(table1, adf.test(i))}
```

As a result, it prints:

```
              statistic parameter alternative   p.value                       method data.name
Dickey-Fuller -7.318571         5  stationary 0.0100000 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test         i
2             -2.829928         7  stationary 0.2269262 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test         i
```

Note that "data.name" prints out "i", instead of "air, co2". Others are correct.

**How do I print out "air" and "co2" in my table?**

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to initiate `table1` and then run a `for` loop here. You can get the same result (with the same problem) using a single line like `do.call(rbind, lapply(lista, adf.test))`.

Comment: It works very well! I just changed to "lista = list( air = ts(AirPassengers, co2 = ts(co2))", because when I run do.call, if my variables doesn't have names, it will return "1, 2", and data.name = X[[i]].

Answer (score 2):

It does not keep the name of the data because you iterate over the list, hence your name becomes the name of your iteration variable, in this case, `i`. You can easily solve this by reassigning the names from your list:

```
table1$data.name <- names(lista)
```

Comment: table1$data.name = names(lista)
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data.name, value = c("air", "co2")) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0

Comment: Interesting, somehow the list lost its names. You can easily fix that by slightly changing your original list: `lista = list(air = air, co2 = co2)`. Then the `data.names` are back in the list. By the way if this answers your question you can click the checkmark to accept it :)

Comment: It does! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> FWIW, you don't need to initiate table1 and then run a for loop here.
>   You can get the same result (with the same problem) using a single
>   line like do.call(rbind, lapply(lista, adf.test)) @ulfelder

Thanks! For that to work, I changed the code because it was getting this result:

```
#     statistic parameter alternative  p.value   method                         data.name
#[1,] -7.318571 5         "stationary" 0.01      "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test" "X[[i]]" 
#[2,] -2.829928 7         "stationary" 0.2269262 "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test" "X[[i]]"
```

Which doesn't show any name of time series. I just changed the code so the name appears:

```
library(tseries)

lista = list (air = ts(AirPassengers), co2 = ts(co2))

do.call(rbind, lapply(lista, adf.test))
```

Which get as result:

```
#        statistic parameter alternative  p.value   method                         data.name
#    air -7.318571 5         "stationary" 0.01      "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test" "X[[i]]" 
#    co2 -2.829928 7         "stationary" 0.2269262 "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test" "X[[i]]"
```

Note that data.name still getting "X[[i]]", but at the beginning you can find "air" and "co2", which attends what I want.

Thanks @ulfelder for your help!